# Transformar de excel (xlsx) a pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, conversión-de-tipos

Estoy hace un tiempo tratando de transformar archivos Excel ([Mi archivo Excel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uHFr6w_nHywt_PoOewgv9ilK2AUZpzTZ/view?usp=sharing)) a PDF, mediante Python he intentado de varias formas pero en ninguna he tenido éxito.

Adjunto un pequeño código y el error que me sale, de antemano muchas gracias

```
from win32com import client

xlApp = client.Dispatch("")
books = Workbooks('EETT- EDUARDO AURELIO SANTANDER  SEPÚLVEDA.xlxs')    
ws = books.Worksheets[0]
ws.Visible = 1
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,'prueba.pdf' )
print("PPTX to PDF conversion sucessful and Saved")
```

[image: Error que me laza en el codigo]

Si poseen algún otro método es bienvenido

Comment: creo que el problema se debe a los espacios, cambia el nombre del archivo a uno mas corto o cambia los espacios, no soy experto, solo es una suposición

Comment: Me lanza el mismo error

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿Qué versión de python estas usando?

Comment: como dije no soy experto en eso, tal vez mi compa @AnkiJedi te ayude

Comment: jajaja tampoco soy experto pero me dio curiosidad que este usando win32com

Comment: ¿Qué tienes en la línea 81 de tu código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero debes de colocar el tipo de programa del que quieres hacer instancia en el metodo `Dispatch()` en tu caso es `excel` por tanto debería ser `client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")`

Segundo en la siguiente linea:

```
books = Workbooks('EETT- EDUARDO AURELIO SANTANDER  SEPÚLVEDA.xlxs')
```

Usas `Workbooks` pero en ningún momento lo declaras, pero este es parte de la instancia de `excel` ya creada así que debería quedar así(ademas para pasarle el directorio debes usar el método `Open()`:

```
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(currentDir,"EETT- EDUARDO AURELIO SANTANDER  SEPÚLVEDA.xlxs"))  #en un momento explico porque uso el os.path.join()
```

Por lo demás no hay muchos cambios importantes, `ws.Visible = 1` no vi que afectara en algo y el export no mas le agregue un `os.path.join()`, y como el método `Open()` deja abierto el archivo excel hay que cerrarlo al final con un `Close()`, el código quedaría así:

```
from win32com import client
import os
#currentDir = os.path.abspath('.')
currentDir = os.getcwd()
xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(currentDir,"EETT- EDUARDO AURELIO SANTANDER  SEPÚLVEDA.xlxs"))    
ws = books.Worksheets[0]
ws.Visible = 1
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,os.path.join(currentDir,"prueba.pdf") )
books.Close()
print("PPTX to PDF conversion sucessful and Saved")
```

**Explicación uso del `os.path.join()`**
Tuve que usar este método porque tanto el `Open()` de `Workbooks` como `ExportAsFixedFormat()` solo toman direcciones de archivos absolutas por eso primero he creado la variable `currentDir` que guarde la dirección absoluta del directorio del archivo y con `os.path.join()` unir este directorio con el nombre del archivo.

Resultado de uso con el archivo excel presentado en la publicación:
[Archivo pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TZCzT5Yc_Dq7PRUCEpVju2F-Tpl5pzb3/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: lo probe y me tira el siguiente error :   'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\carla\OneDrive\Escritorio\trabajo\excelToPdf.py", line 6, in <module>
    books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(currentDir,"h.xlxs"))
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 5, in Open
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ocurrió una excepción.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Lo sentimos, no hemos encontrado C:\\Users\\carla\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\trabajo\\h.xlxs. ¿Puede ser que lo haya movido, eliminado o le hayas cambiado el nombre?', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)'

Comment: Muestra el error porfavor, capaz tiene que ver con el directorio

Comment: ahí sale que estas tratando de entrar al archivo excel h.xlxs y no lo encuentra, seguro que ese es el nombre?

Comment: Edite el comentario y lo escribi, no pude adjuntar una foto. Muchas gracias

Comment: claro, es que era demasiado largo el nombre del archivo, se lo cambie a h

Comment: weird, y se encuentra en esa carpeta trabajo? si es así intenta cambiar el valor de currentDir por os.path.abspath('.')

Comment: Procura que el archivo python y el excel estén en la misma carpeta (esto era lo primero jaja xP)

Comment: si, se encuentra en la carpeta, ahora lo pruebo. Adjunte el link del archivo que quiero transformar a la publicación, ¿Quizás sea el contenido del archivo?

Comment: lo dudo, en el error sale que no encuentra el archivo así que siquiera lo abre

Comment: me arroja el mismo error, tu lo pudiste probar?

Comment: quizas tengo algo mal instalado

Comment: Descargo tu excel y te digo

Comment: muchisimas gracias, quedo atenta

Comment: Vale, probe con tu excel y sin alterar el codigo que te estoy dando y me funciona a la perfección, editare mi respuesta con el link del archivo pdf resultante como prueba

Comment: El problema de la ubicación del archivo excel que tienes esta raro... intenta lo que te mencione de cambiar currentDir por os.path.abspath('.') si no dentro de Open() coloca la dirección que te aparezca en la carpeta del archivo y +el nombre del archivo :*